# Visual Studio Intellisense format XML tags

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, intellisense, xml-documentation

Whenever I write my own XML comments and use some of the helpful tags like `<c></c>` or `<see cref=""/>`, the intellisense popup window shows the literal XML instead of applying any formatting.  I typically write XML comments just for the sake of intellisense rather than to build documentation with sandcastle.  Is there a way to get intellisense to format my XML tags, or should I abandon them altogether?

I see the same behavior in both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code.

#### edit

I deserved that downvote.  After researching further, I see there's a lot more that I missed in the original question.  The problem only occurs when I am writing a "shortcut" comment, where I leave off the actual XML tag for `<summary>`, for example:

```
/// Adds 2 to <c>x</c>
int Add2(int x) => x + 2;
```

Those comments still show up in the XML document, and I thought it was just shorthand for a comment that only includes a summary.

Furthermore, I also discovered that the behavior for those "shortcut" comments is different for different languages.  F# displays the problem as I described in my original post:
[image]

Meanwhile, C# just doesn't render any sort of comment in the intellisense popup at all:
[image]

I suspect now that my answer is just that Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code don't really like comments where you leave off the `<summary>` tag.

Comment: This has probably been answered somewhere on the internet already, but man, have I had a hard time finding it.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show an example.

Comment: @NathanWilson, do you still have issues now? If so, please feel free to let us know :)